# 301 redirect old urls to new urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting my old dynamic urls to new urls like this:

from :

```
http://example.com/movie/movie-name
```

to:

```
http://example.com/movie_id-movie_name-example.html
```

where movie id and movie name is variable here was my old htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?movie/([a-z0-9\-]+)\/?$ index.php?menu=watchmovie&perma=$1&lang=en [L]
```

and here is my new htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)-example\.html$ index.php?menu=watchmovie&perma=$2&lang=en&id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Good for you! Unfortunately I'm not sure what your question is...

Comment: old links are in this shape http://example.com/movie/movie-name  and now new links are in this shape http://example.com/movie_id-movie_name-example.html according to my htaccess so i want and 301 of old links to new links

Comment: still no question.

Comment: post a real url example, you can change your site name

Comment: http://example.com/47180-the-jungle-book-2016-example.html this is my real link(also new one) and that was my old link http://example.com/movie/the-jungle-book-2016 so i want my all old links to redirect 301 to new one.

Comment: Where does the **movieid** come from in your new url?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)-example\.html$ index.php?menu=watchmovie&perma=$2&lang=en&id=$1 [L]

Comment: Your old uri doesnt have the id segment, so how can we redirect dynamically from **movie_name** to **movie_id** ?

Comment: assume i placed id in old uri.

Answer (score 1):

Add **underscores** to you regex, assuming the url is :

`http://yoursite.com/978632-the_hunter.html`

you'll need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-_]+)-example\.html$ index.php?menu=watchmovie&perma=$2&lang=en&id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: bro that Is already in my htaccess and also in my question :S i dont know why you paste my question as my answer :D

Comment: Where's the underscore on the regex ? `([a-z0-9\-_]+)`

Comment: @1337 Curious... You ask an unclear question, we do our best to help you and in the end you don't pay attention to my answer and tell me that I'm copying your question ?! strange...

Comment: bro you just paste my htaccess back what do i say I much appreciate all the help

Comment: @1337 Be respectful! Read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask any question.